# Adding Brightness/Gamma Control to objective-c Custom Video Camera Application with OpenCV Image Recognition

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, avcapturesession, core-image

I have a custom iOS iPhone Camera app in objective-c that displays the video camera stream in a preview layer and captures a frame when a specific object is in the Field of View.  The image recognition is implemented with OpenCV.

The app is working fine, but I would like to give the user the ability to control the brightness/gamma of the video stream and have the modified image captured from the brightness controlled stream.

I know how to create the slider control but I cant find how to control the brightness/gamma of the video image from the camera and display it in the preview layer.  The camera is set up with the following AVCapture Session.

```
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) 
    {
    if(granted){ // Access has been granted ..do something
         NSLog(@"Camera Status Access Granted By User");
               //Setup Video Camera and START
         self.videoCamera = [[VideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:self->_img];
         self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
         self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
         self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = 
              AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
         self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 60;
         self.videoCamera.rotateVideo = NO;
         self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
         self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
         [self.videoCamera start];
    }
```

How do I control the brightness/gamma of the live video stream and display it in the preview layer so as I can then capture the modified image.

Here is the setup of the Preview Layer.

```
- (void)layoutPreviewLayer {
if (self.parentView != nil) {

    // Center the video preview.
    self.customPreviewLayer.position = CGPointMake(0.5 * self.parentView.frame.size.width, 
    0.5 * self.parentView.frame.size.height);

    // Find the video's aspect ratio.
    CGFloat videoAspectRatio = self.imageWidth / (CGFloat)self.imageHeight;

    // Scale the video preview while maintaining its aspect ratio.
    CGFloat boundsW;
    CGFloat boundsH;
    if (self.imageHeight > self.imageWidth) {
        if (self.letterboxPreview) {
            boundsH = self.parentView.frame.size.height;
            boundsW = boundsH * videoAspectRatio;
        } else {
            boundsW = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
            boundsH = boundsW / videoAspectRatio;
        }
    } else {
        if (self.letterboxPreview) {
            boundsW = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
            boundsH = boundsW / videoAspectRatio;
        } else {
            boundsH = self.parentView.frame.size.height;
            boundsW = boundsH * videoAspectRatio;
        }
    }
    self.customPreviewLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, boundsW, boundsH);
  }
}
```

Any code, help and guidance would be greatly appreciated to get this set up.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few ways to achieve this and thought I'd post them here to help anyone else that needs it.

Option 1.

Modify the pixels of the OpenCV Mat to make them lighter or darker with this code using a slider.

```
float gammaValue = 1.5;

//EXPOSURE CONTROL USING OPENCV
- (void) gammaCorrection: (cv::Mat &)mat;
{
    float fGamma = gammaValue;
    mat.convertTo(mat, -1, fGamma, 1 ); //Control the brightness by fGamma
    NSLog(@"Gamma Value is: %f", fGamma);

}


- (IBAction)changeExposureTargetBias:(id)sender {
    UISlider *control = sender;
    NSLog(@"Target Bias %f", control.value );
    gammaValue = control.value;
}
```

Option 2.

Control the exposure of the AVCaptureDevice with a slider.  Exposure bias range for my device was -8.0 to +8.0

```
float exposureBIAS = 0.0;

- (void)setExposure:(float)exposureBIAS
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom])
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ( [device lockForConfiguration:&error] ) {
            [device setExposureTargetBias:exposureBIAS completionHandler:nil];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else {
            NSLog( @"Could not lock device for configuration: %@", error );
        }
    }
}


- (IBAction)changeExposureTargetBias:(id)sender {

    UISlider *control = sender;    
    [self setExposure: control.value];

}
```